# Application not writing file

Tags: java

As a beginner, I am trying to print a set of info to a file called "Sign_in.txt" but this code only creates the file and doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
String nu="CUSTOMER DETAILS START";
    String enu="CUSTOMER DETAILS END";
    n=namefield.getText();
    a=agefield.getText();
    ad=adfield.getText();
    s=salfield.getText();
    p=phfield.getText();
    d=dobfield.getText();
    e=emfield.getText();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(nu);
    list.add(n);
    list.add(a);
    list.add(ad);
    list.add(s);
    list.add(p);
    list.add(d);
    list.add(e);
    list.add(u);
    list.add(q);
    list.add(enu);

    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Sign_in.txt",true)))) {
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(out);
    int l = list.size();

            for(int i = 0; i<l; i++){
                output.write(list.get(i).toString()+"\n");
            }
    output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Thank you for registering");
    System.exit(0);
    new accpage().setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You are using try-with-resources already. No need to close output explicitly.

Comment: Does this compile? Have you tried flushing your output stream?

Comment: Instead of the for loop over `i`, use an enhanced for loop `for (String item : list) {`. (Also no need to call `toString()` on `list.get(i).toString()`, since it is already a `String`).

Comment: So many ``Writer``s...

Comment: You probably shouldn't call `System.exit(0)`, I'm pretty sure the Swing API has better methods of exiting Swing applications.

Comment: I would suggest removing the output variable and using the out PrintWriter directly. You can then use the println method on the PrintWriter, instead of the low-level write method. No need to append the newline char at then end if you're using println. Also, unless you're appending to an existing file, there's no need for the boolean in the FileWriter constructor.

Comment: Ok so thanks to Coffee Monkey I have the whole list printing apart from String enu for some reason.

Comment: Did you try flushing the `PrintWriter` after the `for` loop? [`PrintWriter#flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush%28%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have something like this:

```
try (PrintWriter output = 
         new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Sign_in.txt")))) 
{            
    for (String line: list) {
        output.println(line);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(
                               new BufferedOutputStream(
                                     new FileOutputStream("Sign_in.txt")), true)) 
   {            
        int l = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            output.println(list.get(i).toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```